# Can you monitor the health of a WCF Service hosted in a Console Application using third party software?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a windows application that has a WCF service that is hosted in a console application. The service stops intermittently every couple of months. I have now been asked if there is any way to be notified when the service stops working.

This is legacy code that I am working with.  I cannot touch any of it and redeploy. Is there any way to monitor the health a WCF service hosted in a console application using a third party tool?

Comment: If you want there to be of course.. but this wouldnt be a stack overflow conversation

Comment: @BugFinder how is this not a stack overflow conversation?

Comment: Because asking for off-site resources (such as third-party software) is off-topic as explained in [help/on-topic].

Comment: @CodeCaster oh ok sorry well I am at a loss as to how to resolve the issues I am having without touching the code, and am not to sure were to look for answers, and was hoping to get help with this as I have not worked with WCF services before and know little about them. I have googled and found tools but I am not sure if this is even the right approach. I was looking for some insight into WCF services and monitoring the health of it.

Comment: Whenever that wcf stops, let it make an entry point in event viewer or log it's status somewhere in your application folder so that you can check logs or event viewer and be informed about application status.

Comment: If you can define "health", I'm sure you can find something. Determine what exactly you want to monitor. Availability? Uptime? Response times? And so on.

Comment: I need to know the up time and when it stops working because supposedly it stops working for no reason and no one knows why and when. They wanted to know it stopped working and if an email notification could be sent to them when this happens so that they could start it again or figure out why it stopped in the first place.

Comment: @Hameed like I mentioned in the questions I cannot make any changes to the original code as I don't not know what the knock on effects are, and to my knowledge there is already error handling like this in place, but still nothing is being logged.